# Confused by NSString immutability

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I am an Objective-C newbie. I am struggling with the twin concepts of mutability/immutability.
I am ploughing through a book called Programming in Objective-C 4th Edition. Chapter 15 talks about the `NSString` class which is stated to be immutable. The book then provides examples which seem to contradict that e.g.:

```
NSString *str1 = @"this is string A";
NSString *str2 = @"this is string B";

str2 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:str2];

NSString *res; 

res = [str1 substringToIndex:3];
res = [str1 substringFromIndex:5];
res = [[str1 substringFromIndex:8]substringToIndex:6];
res = [str1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8, 6)];
```

So even though 'res' is a pointer to an immutable object, its value has changed several times, so how can this be called immutable? I guess I am completely missing the point. Any advice, gratefully received.

Answer (score 4):

In the following lines:

```
NSString *str2 = @"this is string B";
str2 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:str2];
```

You don't change the **content** of the string "this is string B" (that were stored in variable `str2`), you make the variable `str2` point to a different string (a **new** string that is generated by the `stringByAppendingString:` method).

The difference here is quite the same as in C between `const char*` and `char* const`.

- `NSString*` and `const char*` both denote a pointer to a string (Cocoa or C resp.) whose content can't be changed. The variable can still point to a different string, but the original string won't change its content.
- That's different from a constant pointer to a string like `char* const` or `NSMutableString* const`, which is a constant pointer to a mutable string, meaning the content of the string itself can be changed, but the variable/pointer will always point to the same address in memory.

---

Study this example:

```
NSString* str1 = @"A";
NSString* str2 = str1; // points to the same immutable string
NSString* str3 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:@"B"];
// Now str1 and str2 both point to the string "A" and str3 points to a new string "AB"
str2 = str3;
// Now str2 points to the same string as str3 (same memory address and all)
// So str1 points to string "A" and str2 and str3 both point to "B"
```

Note that in that example, str1 hasn't changed and is still `"A"`. It has not been mutated.
This is different than with this other example:

```
NSMutableString* str1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"A"];
NSMutableString* str2 = str1; // points to the same mutable string
[str2 appendString:@"B"];
// Now str1 and str2 still both point to the same string, but
// this same string has been mutated and is now "AB"
// So the string that previously was "A" is now "AB" but is still as the same address in memory
// and both str1 and str2 points to this address so are BOTH equal to string "AB"
```

In this second example, the string is mutated, so both variables `str1` and `str2` that are pointing to this string now contains "AB".

Answer (score 3):

The *content* of the string object is immutable. You can still take the pointer and make it point to an other object.

```
NSString *s = @"string1";
s = @"string2"
```

This doesn't change the content of the first string object. It simply allocates a new string object and makes `*s` point to it. There will still be a string object "string1" in memory (if you're not using ARC) with nothing pointing to it (and be released later).

Try this:

```
NSString *s = @"string1";
NSLog(@"String object at address %p has content %@.", s, s);
s = @"string2";
NSLog(@"String object at address %p has content %@.", s, s);
```

```
Test[1819:303] String object at address 0x100002890 has content string1.
Test[1819:303] String object at address 0x1000028d0 has content string2.
```

As you can see, a new instance was created at a different address.

Methods that start with the name of the class (like `stringWith...` or `arrayWith...`) usually return a new instance of that class.

You can do the same test as above with one of those methods:

```
NSString *s = @"string1";
NSLog(@"String object at address %p ha content %@", s, s);
s = [s substringToIndex:3];
NSLog(@"String object at address %p ha content %@", s, s);
```

```
Test[1857:303] String object at address 0x1000028a0 ha content string1
Test[1857:303] String object at address 0x10012ab70 ha content str
```

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the explanation. So this begs the question: If the original string is leaked when the pointer points to a new string, is it ever a good idea to change an immutable string?

Comment: Good point. It isn't leaked, it's autoreleased (released some time later), so that's fine as long as you don't autorelease thousands of strings every frame or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are changing WHAT `res` is pointing to, not changing the contents of what it is pointing at.